# Should I use MySQL indexes of MD5 32 chars or a ~8 chars index that contains special chars?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, database-performance

I have a database of around 100 million urls, and for sharding purposes (and to identify unique urls) I made each entry index to be a md5 hash of the full url.

MD5 is made of only 16 possible characters: `0123456789abcdef` with a 32 chars total length.

What performance benefits should I expect (if any) if I use shorter indexes like 8 total characters ? e.g using a hashing function (maybe custom) that includes uppercase, lowercase and special characters.

Or would it be a performance degradation because the indexes use way more possible characters ? (even if index length is shorter ~8).

Comment: This is one of those questions that's best answered pragmatically, through benchmarking *on the specific hardware and software you have in mind for deployment*, rather than going with a wild guess based on theory. MySQL behaves in entirely unpredictable ways when put under actual load.

Comment: It's also worth noting that MD5 is pretty flimsy and if you have that many entries you might actually have collisions. Worth checking. SHA2-256 is a safer bet, but that might defeat the purpose here.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**  I recommend Plan C with `INDEX(hash, id)`, making sure it is a *secondary* index.

**Long answer** and some discussion:

Plan A:  Just use the url.  Least efficient.

Plan B:  Use the 32-byte `CHAR(32) CHARSET ascii` for hex MD5.  Better but not best.

Plan C:  `UNHEX(..)` and put into `BINARY(16)` (16 bytes).  Better.

Plan D (as you suggest):  Use only some of those 16 bytes.  There *will* be some duplicates.  This may defeat the speed benefit of using a shorter digest.

Plan E:  Bit pattern plus lookup.  Possibly even faster.  (But first, let me explain some of the issues.)

How much RAM do you have?  How much disk do you have?

Presumably you have the 10-20GB needed on disk.  But do you also have more than that much in RAM?  If you don't then we need to discuss shrinking the lookup, else *all* Plans will degenerate into having to hit the disk with some frequency.

What does the table look like?

- hash + full URL + miscellany; with either `id` or `hash` as `PRIMARY KEY`
- INDEX(hash, id) -- You would spend most of the effort here, and this is much smaller than the full table.  This secondary index, with Plan C, would take about 5GB for 100M rows.  You would be jumping around, thereby not very cacheable unless all 5GB can survive in RAM.
- Plan E tries to shrink the index by first looking in a bit string that can compress the lookup into perhaps 0.2GB.  There *will* be duplicates that would need to be double-checked (with, say, plan C), but only perhaps 5-10% of the time.  We can discuss this further if you like.

For further discussion, please provide RAM size, and full `CREATE TABLE` and the proposed "check for dup" `SELECT`.

**Sizes**

- 1 bit can represent only 2 different values
- 1 hex digit can represent only 4 different values
- 1 byte (8 bits) can represent 256 (2^8) different values
- 100M ~= 2^23 (for comparison)
- INT is 4 bytes: 2^32, big enough for holding 1..100M
- BIGINT is 8 bytes: 2^64, bigger than is needed for virtually all `id` usages
- 8 bytes, assuming you use all possibly combinations:  256^8 = 2^64 = a-very-large-number
- MD5 has 128 bits (represented either as 32 hex digits or 16 binary bytes):  2^128 -- an even bigger number

To judge the likelihood of a duplicate:

- Given 2^M -- For example M=128 for MD5; 64 for BIGINT
- Compute N=(M+1)/3 -- MD5: 43; BIGINT: ~22
- Say:  The odds of finding a dup in 2^N rows is 1/2^N.

That is,

- The odds of a dup with md5:  If you have 2^43 (9 trillion) values is only 1 in 9 trillion.
- The odds of a dup with an 8-byte hash:  If you have 6 million rows, the chance of a dup is about 1 in 6 million.